# Reading soap xml generated from WSDL interface file

Tags: xml, delphi, soap, delphi-xe

I have created half a SOAP interface in Delphi, in an attempt understand how it works. I want to see the XML generated by the file written out, but as newbe in XML I am not sure how to get it. I have already had help to get it at the Server end, but I want to be able to check it without having to set up the code in a Server for each interface.

Here is the code:

```
interface

uses Soap.InvokeRegistry, Soap.SOAPHTTPClient, System.Types, Soap.XSBuiltIns;

type

  IHello = interface(IInvokable)
  ['{243CBD89-8766-F19D-38DF-427D7A02EAEE}']
    function  sayHello(const firstName: string): string; stdcall;
  end;

function GetIHello(UseWSDL: Boolean=System.False; Addr: string=''; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO = nil): IHello;


implementation
  uses System.SysUtils;

function GetIHello(UseWSDL: Boolean; Addr: string; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO): IHello;
const
  defWSDL = 'http://localhost:8080/wsdl/IHello';
  defURL  = 'http://localhost:8080/soap/IHello';
  defSvc  = 'IHelloservice';
  defPrt  = 'IHelloPort';
var
  RIO: THTTPRIO;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if (Addr = '') then
  begin
    if UseWSDL then
      Addr := defWSDL
    else
      Addr := defURL;
  end;
  if HTTPRIO = nil then
    RIO := THTTPRIO.Create(nil)
  else
    RIO := HTTPRIO;
  try
    Result := (RIO as IHello);
    if UseWSDL then
    begin
      RIO.WSDLLocation := Addr;
      RIO.Service := defSvc;
      RIO.Port := defPrt;
    end else
      RIO.URL := Addr;
  finally
    if (Result = nil) and (HTTPRIO = nil) then
      RIO.Free;
  end;
end;

initialization
  { Hello_PortType }
  InvRegistry.RegisterInterface(TypeInfo(IHello), 'Ihelloservice', '');
  InvRegistry.RegisterDefaultSOAPAction(TypeInfo(IHello), 'sayHello');

end.
```

Comment: Can't Delphi automatically generate client classes from the WSDL URL?

Comment: Yes. That it what you see above. I just want to interrogate the result after I call the function GetIHello. I can do that OK, and it doesn't crash, but that is all I know. I should be able to interrogate the string output to that function, but cannot work out how to do that. I sure it is easy (if you know how). The function just returns a pointer to the interface. How do get the interrogate the string? Or should I be looking somewhere else?

Comment: Have I approached this from the wrong end. Should I have created the server first and created a WSDL file from the server? Is that the more usual approach?